# Trigger isn't inserting the correct row

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this trigger I made

```
alter trigger fuzzylogic  on oehdrhst_sql

for insert
as
begin
declare @ordno char(8)
declare @rownum int
declare @id int

select @ordno = ord_no from inserted
select @rownum = a.id from banktransactions a  where convert(char(8),a.OwnReference) = (select ord_no from inserted)


select @id = a.id from banktransactions a join inserted i on i.ord_no = a.invoicenumber
where a.invoicenumber = @ordno
begin
    insert into triggertest values(@ordno,@rownum,@id)
    update banktransactions set matchid = @rownum,SupplierInvoiceNumber = @ordno where id = @id
end
end
```

When I look inside triggertest after I insert a row I see the ordno and the rownum but I keep getting nulls on the id

I ran this sql statement to test to see if the query wouldn't return anything but it did.

```
select a.id from banktransactions a join oehdrhst_sql b on a.invoicenumber = b.ord_no
```

Why won't the variable print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> select @ordno = ord_no from inserted

This logic is fundamentally flawed. If you insert more than one row, what value do you expect to be assigned to the variable? It will be arbitrary. Triggers fire per statement, not per row.

You need to update your trigger to handle multi-row inserts. Without schema, sample data and desired results, this is a wild fuzzy guess at the trigger logic you should be using instead of assigning an arbitrary row from `inserted`:

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.fuzzylogic -- always use dbo prefix!
ON dbo.oehdrhst_sql -- always use dbo prefix!
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT dbo.triggertest -- always use schema prefix!
    -- where is your column list?
    SELECT i.ord_no, b1.id, b2.id
    FROM inserted AS i
    INNER JOIN dbo.banktransactions AS b1 -- always use schema prefix!
    ON i.ord_no = CONVERT(CHAR(8), b1.OwnReference)
    INNER JOIN dbo.banktransactions AS b2 -- always use schema prefix!
    ON i.ord_no = b2.invoicenumber;

  UPDATE b
    SET matchid = b1.id, SupplierInvoiceNumber = i.ord_no
    FROM dbo.banktransactions AS b
    INNER JOIN dbo.banktransactions AS b2 -- always use schema prefix!
    ON b.id = b2.id
    INNER JOIN inserted AS i 
    ON i.ord_no = b2.invoicenumber
    INNER JOIN dbo.banktransactions AS b1 -- always use schema prefix!
    ON i.ord_no = CONVERT(CHAR(8), a.OwnReference);
END
GO
```

This may be totally wrong, but again it's hard to tell without more insight into your system (or why three different rows in a bank transactions table should be related - yikes!). It should at least give you a start.

Comment: would you share how to do that?